# Set permission to read local XML file in C# for XAML browser app

Tags: c#, xml, xbap, securityexception

I have a XAML Browser Application that will eventually be placed on a server, however I am currently testing it from my Documents folder. I am trying to read from an XML document locally, but I am stuck at `XmlReader.Create();`
When I tried to use my XML document, a SecurityException was thrown, so I tried to use the following to bestow read permission upon the XML file:

```
FileIOPermission fpa1 = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, @"C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WpfBrowserApplication2\WpfBrowserApplication2\XMLDoc1.xml");
xReader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WpfBrowserApplication2\WpfBrowserApplication2\XMLDoc1.xml"
```

The error message reads:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[tokennumber]' failed.
```

Is FileIOPermission the correct class to use to enable read permission with an XmlReader?

Comment: Perhaps as a workaround you could let the user upload the XML to the application, instead of having the application try to read it off the disk?

Comment: Ideally I'd like the application to manage the XML file and eventually read and write various properties that could be used to create and load objects into the application, so the user would not have to do anything with the XML file (nor would they possess the file to create the initial objects). The application would remove the need for the user to type anything in the XML document.

Answer (score 0):

The FileIOPermission class is used to check if you have the permission, not to set it.

IE:

```
try
{
    FileIOPermission perf = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, @"C:\Users\jbeaulac\Documents\test.xml");
    perf.Demand();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not enough permission, blah blah blah.");
    return;
}


var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Users\jbeaulac\Documents\test.xml");
/// ...
```

From a XBAP application you cannot randomly mess with the user's files, unless your application is full trust.

Project Properties --> Security --> This is a full trust application

Also, if you plan on using XBAP this documentation is really worth reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970910.aspx